# Object exists in two states when overwriting prototype in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get my head around Object Oriented Programming in Javascript and bumped into the following issue: (This is a simplified example of what can be found in Stoyan Stefanov's book)

I create a constructor function to create Dog objects:

```
function Dog(){
this.tail = true;
}
```

Then I instantiate an object using Dog constructor function:

```
var benji = new Dog();
```

Then I assign a new property to Dog's prototype object:

```
Dog.prototype.shout = 'Woof!';
```

Now, benji has access to both tail, as well as shout, as expected. All is well until I overwrite Dog's prototype:

```
Dog.prototype = {paw : 4};
```

Now, benji.paw becomes undefined. My question is, shouldn't benji have access to the new prototype object as well? What's more baffling is, when I create a new instance of Dog after the prototype object was re-defined:

```
var lucy = new Dog();
```

lucy.paw evaluates to 4. lucy's constructor object definition seems to be different from benji's. I am quite confused what's going on here, can someone explain how javascript's memory model for objects work? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`prototype` is just an object.

If you do

`var oldProto = Dog.prototype`

before you overwrite it

`Dog.prototype = { paws: 4 }`

then you can use the old prototype object for manipulations of its children:

`oldProto.teeth = true` —> `benji.teeth == true`.

Comment: Thanks, didn't really see the prototype as an object until this point.